# ng-repeat and filter not working AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have an array which I print out it's elements based on which category is selected

```
<li class="thumbnail" ng-repeat="temp in templates| filter:{temp.category_id :       selectedCategoryId }:true">
```

templates looks like this :

```
[{"id":"1","account_id":null,"category_id":"1","name":"Blue","thumbnail":"placehold.it/210x300","category_name":"test"},{"id":"2","account_id":null,"category_id":"1","name":"Red","thumbnail":"placehold.it/210x300","category_name":"test"},{"id":"3","account_id":null,"category_id":"2","name":"Green","thumbnail":"placehold.it/210x300","category_name":"test again"}]
```

Thanks for the help !

EDIT :
I also wanted to add an extra condition , that is temp.category_id == null , show all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify temp again in the filter.

Change

```
 filter:{temp.category_id : selectedCategoryId }:true
```

To

```
 filter:{category_id : selectedCategoryId }:true
```

Here's a fiddle of it working:  http://jsfiddle.net/Sqq3s/

Comment: If I wanted to also add an extra condition , for example that if selectedCategoryId == null then show all

Comment: You can stack filters.  But they're additive (the results of one flow into the next).  So that won't help you show all if no options are found.  An approach to that is to have an additional display block controlled by an `ng-show` that is triggered if selectedCategoryID == null.

Comment: <li class="thumbnail" ng-repeat="temp in templates | filter:{selectedCategoryId : null }:true">  Does not seem to be working

Comment: `selectedCategoryID == null` would be used within an `ng-show` (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngShow) that controls a separate dom element which displays everything.  Think of this as entirely separate from your `ng-repeat`.  If you really need `ng-repeat` to handle all of this you could write a custom filter.  But that's a bit more complex than using `ng-show` on a new dom element.

Answer (score 0):

Your filter should be:

```js
<li ng-repeat="temp in templates | filter:{category_id : selectedCategoryId}:true"> ... </li>
```

Writing `filter: {temp.category_id : selectedCategoryId}` would look for property `temp.category_id` (which is an invalid name for a property, it should read `'temp.category_id'`) in the `temp` object. However, you want to look for the property `category_id`.